# Leaflet map: Rotated Marker for ionic2 (Typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, leaflet

I'm a typescript "newbie", currently working on an ionic2 project (Typescript) that use leaflet v1.1.0 as a map. I need to rotate a marker. In previous projects (JavaScript) I was using [Leaflet.RotatedMarker](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker). But this plugin isn't typed and It can't be used in my current project.

I need help either finding a way to use leaflet rotated marker plugin or to create the marker rotation behavior directly in my code.

Comment: I am having this issue. is it possible to write a type definition file of it ?

Answer (score 7):

Since a few months TypeScript type definitions for Leaflet.RotatedMarker are provided here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commits/master/types/leaflet-rotatedmarker

You need to install them **@types/leaflet-rotatedmarker** in addition to **leaflet-rotatedmarker**

If you're using npm you just need to install both packages:

`npm i -S @types/leaflet-rotatedmarker leaflet-rotatedmarker`

Then you can set the **rotationAngle** on your marker.

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-rotatedmarker';
...
 let marker = L.marker([47,18], {         
          rotationAngle: 180
          icon: ...,
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution I've used L.divIcon and it work perfectly

```
L.divIcon({
  html: '<img class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated" src="[icon image URL]" style="width: [icon width]px; height: [icon height]px;transform: rotate([angle]deg);  -webkit-transform: rotate([angle]deg); -moz-transform:rotate([angle]deg);" />'
})
```

Comment: It would be great if you explain to me how you manage to resolve you problem. I have the same use case as yours. regards.

Comment: @ferouk, appreciate it if you could share with us if there is a new development on this. Thanks.

Comment: Rotated marker was finally typed 
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commits/master/types/leaflet-rotatedmarker